# Proccessing compare combination of 3 Strings

Tags: java, for-loop, compare, processing

I'm making a small game for a school project. In my game I have 9 cards on a 3x3 field, every card has 3 properties: *count*, *shape* and *color*. You have a set when 3 cards share the same or different properties, so when all colors are the same or different and all three shapes are the same or different and all the colors are the same or different.

For example:

- 1 red triangle, 1 red rectangle, 1 red ellipse.
- 1 blue triangle, 2 green triangle

The 3 priorities have to be the same of have to be different. As you see here above the first card has the same count, different shapes and the same color.

Now I have to make a function that will check how many sets there are on the table. I have a function that will check if 3 cards are a set, but I'm not able to make a function that will check all the possible combinations of 3 cards on the field. The cards on the field are saved in a 2 dimensional array.

My program is in Dutch:

- `setsOpTafel` == sets on the table
- `kaarten` == cards
- `aantalSets` == number of sets

http://pastie.org/private/zqkfhqew1q8kwqvi6cvm0w

Can somebody help please?

edit:
How to function has to work.
so first of i have to check the combo of 3 cards -> card 1, card 2, card3.
Then card 1, card 2, card 4. and so forth till it has checked all the different combination of 3 different cards.

Comment: could you clearify a bit more with text examples.

Comment: Please add an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not your full code.

Comment: Sorry its my first time asking a question on stackoverflow. I will try to clearify its more.

Comment: Then see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: No, i have to compare from the 9 cards on the field all the possible combination with different cards. 1,2,3 and 1,3,2 is the same so that only counts as 1 possiblility

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple solution. I dont know whether it is like you intended or not.
[Run Code](https://ideone.com/W9npnJ)

```
class GAME {

    static class Card {

        public enum Shape {

            square, triangle, circle
        }

        public enum Color {

            red, blue, green
        }
        public int count;
        public Shape shape;
        public Color color;

        public int gencode(boolean difcount, boolean difcolor, boolean difshape) {
            int gen = -1;
            if (difcount == true || difcolor == true || difshape == true) {
                gen = 0;
            }
            if (difcount == true) {
                gen = count+1;//for count=0 
            }
            if (difcolor == true && shape != null) {
                gen += 1000 * (shape.ordinal() + 1);
            }
            if (difshape == true && color != null) {
                gen += 100000 * (color.ordinal() + 1);
            }
            return gen;
        }

        public String  toString() {
            String s = "Card::properties " + count;
            if (color != null) {
                switch (color) {
                    case red:
                        s += " red";
                        break;
                    case blue:
                        s += " blue";
                        break;
                    case green:
                        s += " green";
                        break;
                    default:

                }
            }
            if (shape != null) {
                switch (shape) {
                    case square:
                        s += " square";
                        break;
                    case triangle:
                        s += " triangle";
                        break;
                    case circle:
                        s += " circle";
                        break;
                    default:

                }
            }

           return s;
        }

    }

    public static void add(HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<GAME.Card>> cardmap, GAME.Card card, int key) {
        ArrayList<GAME.Card> cardlist = cardmap.get(key);
        if (cardlist == null) {
            cardlist = new ArrayList<Card>();
            cardlist.add(card);
            cardmap.put(key, cardlist);
            return;
        }
        cardlist.add(card);
        return;
    }

    public static void showGroups( HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<GAME.Card>> cardmap){
        for (List<GAME.Card> value : cardmap.values()) {
            if(value.size()<=1) continue;
            System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------");
            int ii = 0;
            for (GAME.Card p : value) {
                ii += 1;
                System.out.println("" + ii + ") "+p); 
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Integer, ArrayList<GAME.Card>> cardmap = new HashMap< >();
        GAME.Card[] allcards = new Card[9];
     //init here (simple test
     int lennn = GAME.Card.Shape.values().length;
     int lennm = GAME.Card.Color.values().length;
     Random randomGenerator = new Random();
     for (int i = 0; i < allcards.length; i++) {
        int ppp=randomGenerator.nextInt(9); 
        int kkk=randomGenerator.nextInt(2456); 
        allcards[i] = new Card();
        allcards[i].count = ppp ;
        allcards[i].shape = GAME.Card.Shape.values()[ppp % lennn];
        allcards[i].color = GAME.Card.Color.values()[kkk % lennm];
       }
        System.out.println("######## Generated random cards");
          int ii = 0;
            for (GAME.Card p : allcards) {
                ii += 1;
                System.out.println("" + ii + ") "+p); 
            }

        System.out.println("\n########Group at least by one property");
        //group Cards by properties and its values
        for (int i = 0; i < allcards.length; i++) {
            //check one property
            add(cardmap, allcards[i], allcards[i].gencode(true, false, false));
            add(cardmap, allcards[i], allcards[i].gencode(false, true, false));
            add(cardmap, allcards[i], allcards[i].gencode(false, false, true));

        }

        //show groups
        showGroups(cardmap);

        //check two
        System.out.println("\n########Group at least by two properties");
        cardmap = new HashMap< >();
          //group Cards by properties and its values
        for (int i = 0; i < allcards.length; i++) { 
            //check two properties
            add(cardmap, allcards[i], allcards[i].gencode(true, true, false));
            add(cardmap, allcards[i], allcards[i].gencode(true, false, true));
            add(cardmap, allcards[i], allcards[i].gencode(false, true, true));
        }

        //show groups
         showGroups(cardmap);

         //check all
         System.out.println("\n########Group  by all properties");
         cardmap = new HashMap< >();
          //group Cards by properties and its values
        for (int i = 0; i < allcards.length; i++) { 
            //check all properties
            add(cardmap, allcards[i], allcards[i].gencode(true, true, true)); 
        }

        //show groups
         showGroups(cardmap);

    }

}
```